# AWS SNS sending message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We have observed that after we have sent a verification code on text(using aws sns), we are unable to send another code to the same mobile number for 20 minutes. is there any ways the time can be reduced, similar to a banking website where we can send another code to same mobile number within 3-4 minutes.

Comment: *"we are unable to send another code to the same mobile number for 20 minutes"*  What does "unable" mean, specifically?  Do you get an error from SNS, or does the request appear to succeed yet the SMS message never arrives?

Comment: sms arrives after 20 min and also sometimes it never arrives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said SMS arrives after 20 mins or sometimes it doesn't arrive. Seems like a service provider's delay to me.

Do you get any error from SNS? You should check the [CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/MonitorSNSwithCloudWatch.html)'s `NumberOfNotificationsDelivered` and `NumberOfNotificationsFailed` metrics to dig deeper into the problem.